# linux screen on putty prevents midnight commander mouse action

Tags: linux, mouse, putty, gnu-screen, mc

When I am using the linux screen program (for multiple screens) on putty the mouse action in midnight commander is suppressed. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem with using the default screen terminal emulator. To verify, you can supply the screen command with another terminal using the `-T` flag.

```
$ screen -T xterm
```

Run midnight commander and check if you now have mouse support.

To make this the default, add the line `term xterm` to `~/.screenrc` (create the file if it does not exist).

Comment: hi osafi, thanks for your answer. unfortunately this is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/LG/issue23/wkndmech_dec97/mc_article.html) says you need the [gpm mouse server](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-configure-the-mouse-at-a-text-based-terminal-for-copy-and-paste-operation.html) in the console.